# Why do we have 2 home keys on keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I was watching blender's video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxFGm_LQeZQ

The author says press the home key. I press it and nothing happens.

Turns out there are 2 home keys.

The first one is what I usually press on the numpad. It's usually the same key with number 7. If num lock is off it should perform as home key. It doesn't work.

In my keyboard there is another home key on top of it.

I can't really show you my keyboard but you can see keyboard here

[image]

You see there are 2 home keys there. If you look at the num pad, there is Home at number 7. To the left of it there is another button that says Home.

Why 2 of them?

And out of curiosity, why only one of them works at blender.

Comment: Opinion-based. Short answer IBM designed it that way. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_keyboard and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_M_keyboard. Yours is a Model M layout by the way.

Comment: See also https://deskthority.net/wiki/IBM_Enhanced_Keyboard and https://deskthority.net/wiki/IBM_Model_M

Comment: It seems IBM stole the design from DEC :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LK201

Comment: And why does one home key works at blender and the others don't?

Comment: Ergonomics? "The keyboard layout was new at the time, adding a set of cursor and miscellaneous keys between the main keyboard and the numeric keypad. The cursor keys were arranged in what has now become the standard "Inverted T" arrangement seen on essentially all contemporary full-sized computer keyboards."

Comment: No idea about blender. Both keys works in almost all programs. Perhaps blender is doing something special in it's keyboard handling code?

Comment: does the 2 key send different signal? do they have slightly different code?

Comment: They send different codes. The cursor on sends `E0 47`, the numpad one sends `47`. http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/scan.htm

Comment: Correction - it's a Windows 104-key layout not a Model M layout

Answer (score 3):

It's an historic reason, as you can see in this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Num_lock) article:

Most earlier computer keyboards had separate number keys and cursor control keys.

However to reduce cost, IBM chose to combine the two in their early PC (*84-key IBM PC keyboards*)

Num Lock would be used to choose between the two functions.

Comment: That Wikipedia link is hardly definitive. For a start "This article does not cite any sources."